# How to prevent UIwebView refreshing?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have made an app that contains a lot of PDF files that are loaded in the UIwebview. Whenever I open the PDF, close it, and then go back to it, the file starts from the top again, it reloads. I don't want it to reload once the user goes out of the file and comes back to it.

Example of my code is below.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HnonC" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [Webview loadRequest:request];
        [Webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];

        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: any reason you're calling super at the top and bottom of this method?

Comment: How about using a screenshot of the view when the file is first closed, and showing the screenshot while the UIWebView is prepared next time? If you're trying to provide a seamless user experience, this will accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think the `UIWebView` is "refreshing". That would assume the same `UIWebView`. Since you're posting your `-viewDidLoad` code, what is actually happening is that you're creating a whole new `UIViewController`, with all of its properties also being newly created.

The only way I can think of to keep this from happening is to make a `strong` property to the `UIViewController` so that it isn't destroyed when you pop it off the screen (I'm assuming you're "closing" it by popping it off the top of a `UINavigationController` stack). That would explain why your `viewDidLoad` code is running multiple times, since that will run just once per `UIViewController` instance.

So, in your `AppDelegate` (or another app-level singleton object), make a property like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *pdfViewController;
```

Then, when it's time to load the PDF for viewing, you can check to see if this property already exists and, if so, simply push the `UIViewController` that is already in memory. That should maintain the same view that the user was seeing when the `UIViewController` was popped. I would think something like this would work (assuming this code is in an `IBAction` or something):

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *pdfViewController = del.pdfViewController;
if (pdfViewController == nil) {
    pdfViewController = // Some code to create the view controller
    del.pdfViewController = pdfViewController;
} 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfViewController];
```

You can pick what happens by selectively overriding certain view lifecycle methods:

- -viewDidLoad: called once per instance
- -viewWillAppear: called each time view controller is pushed/shown
- -viewDidAppear: called each time view controller is pushed/shown

Of course, if you wish to selectively show one of ***multiple*** PDF files, you will need to also have a property describing which PDF is currently being shown. Whether you make a different `UIViewController` instance (and keep a property to it) per PDF file is up to you. That's definitely a question of your specific problem. This approach will likely cause memory issues after only a few separate instances are loaded simultaneously.